# Problem with drone simulator // [cvg_sim_gazebo] is not a package or launch file name

Tags: ros, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i tried to install package tum_simulator but I found one problem.

When I try to  ........roslaunch cvg_sim_gazebo ardrone_testworld.launch....
the problem is ....
gazebo will b started but the model will not load

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221131/problem-with-drone-simulator-//-%5Bcvg_sim_gazebo%5D-is-not-a-package-or-launch-file-name/) by [M imran](https://answers.ros.org/users/23352/m-imran/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-11-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
echo "source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
```

hope it helps

---

Originally posted by [mohsen1989m](https://answers.ros.org/users/22803/mohsen1989m/) with karma: 397 on 2015-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0